# Comparing two elements by index in a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently going through this course to learn numpy: https://saskeli.github.io/data-analysis-with-python-summer-2019/numpy2.html. I'm currently stuck in Exercise 1 (column comparison).

The exercise states: Write function column_comparison that gets a two dimensional array as parameter. The function should return a new array containing those rows from the input that have the value in the second column larger than in the second last column.

Here's the test array:

```
arr = np.array([[8 ,9 ,3 ,9 ,8],
                [0 ,5 ,3 ,9 ,9],
                [5 ,7 ,6 ,0 ,4],
                [7 ,8 ,1 ,6 ,2],
                [2 ,1 ,3 ,5 ,8],
                              ])
```

I tried these, which print the same output:

```
c = arr[1] > arr[-2]      arr[arr[1] > arr[-2]]

[[5 7 6 0 4]
 [7 8 1 6 2]
 [2 1 3 5 8]]
```

The result should be:

```
[[8 9 3 8 8]
[5 7 6 0 4]
[7 8 1 6 2]]
```

I actually can't even figure out what that does, the last row certainly doesn't satisfy the condition I wanted it to. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not selecting the column

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[8 ,9 ,3 ,9 ,8],
                [0 ,5 ,3 ,9 ,9],
                [5 ,7 ,6 ,0 ,4],
                [7 ,8 ,1 ,6 ,2],
                [2 ,1 ,3 ,5 ,8],
                              ])
print(arr[arr[:,1]>=arr[:,-2]])

[[8 9 3 9 8]
 [5 7 6 0 4]
 [7 8 1 6 2]
```